# MySQL query optimisation, SQL Query is taking too much time

Tags: mysql

```
select * 
from `attendance_marks` 
where exists (select * 
              from `attendables` 
              where `attendance_marks`.`attendable_id` = `attendables`.`id` 
              and `attendable_type` = 'student' 
              and `attendable_id` = 258672 
              and `attendables`.`deleted_at` is null
              ) 
and (`marked_at` between '2022-09-01 00:00:00' and '2022-09-30 23:59:59')
```

this query is taking too much time approx 7-10 seconds.
I am trying to optimize it but stuck at here.

Attendance_marks indexes
[image: Indexs for attendance marks table]

Attendables Indexes
[image: Indexes for attendable table]

Please help me optimize it a little bit.

*For reference*

**number of rows in attendable = 80966**

**number of rows in attendance_marks = 1853696**

Explain select
[image: explain select]

Comment: Use explain select … to see the selected indices

Comment: `attendable_id` = 258672  , `attendance_marks`.`attendable_id` = `attendables`.`id`  ? perhaps ` `attendables`.`id = 258672 `

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if we use `JOINS` instead of `Sub-Query`, then it will be more performant. Unfortunately, I don't have the exact data to be able to benchmark the performance.

```sql
select * 
from attendance_marks 
inner join attendables on attendables.id = attendance_marks.attendable_id
where attendable_type = 'student'
and attendable_id = 258672
and attendables.deleted_at is null
and (marked_at between '2022-09-01 00:00:00' and '2022-09-30 23:59:59')
```

I'm not sure if your business requirement allows changing the PK, and adding index. Incase it does then:

1. Add index to `attendable_id`.
2. I assume that `attendables.id` is PK. Incase not, add an index to it. Or preferably make it the PK.
3. In case `attendable_type` have a lot of different values. Then consider adding an index there too.
4. If possible don't have granularity till the seconds' field in `marked_at`, instead round to the nearest minute. In our case, we can round off `2022-09-30 23:59:59` to `2022-10-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive, so you are including an extra second.  Your use of '*' pulls in the data from the other table; this differs from the original query.  Individual indexes are less useful than a composite index (in this case).

Answer (score 1):

```
select  b.*
    from  `attendance_marks` AS am
    JOIN  `attendables` AS b  ON am.`attendable_id` = b.`id`
    WHERE  b.`attendable_type` = 'student'
      and  b.`attendable_id` = 258672
      and  b.`deleted_at` is null
      AND  am.`marked_at` >= '2022-09-01'
      AND  am.`marked_at` <  '2022-09-01 + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

and have these

```
am:  INDEX(marked_at, attendable_id)
am:  INDEX(attendable_id, marked_at)
b:  INDEX(attendable_type, attendable_id, attendables)
```

Note that the datetime range works for any granularity.

(Be sure to check that I got the aliases for the correct tables.)

This formulation, with these indexes should allow the Optimizer to pick which table is more efficient to start with.